# I would like to solve a system of network-based differential equations using python 3.6

Tags: python, differential-equations, jitcode-jitcdde-jitcsde

I would like to solve a system of network-based differential equations using python 3.6. The system of equations is as follows:

```
dx_i/dt = omega_i  - epsilon_i * y_i * x_i - mu_i * x_i,  

dy_i/dt = epsilon_i * y_i * x_i - zeta_i * y_i - rho_i * y_i * z_i,

dv_i/dt = c_i * y_i - gamma_i * v_i + \sum_{i neq j} beta_{ij} * v_i * x_i,

dz_i/dt = k_i * y_i * z_i - delta_i * z_i,

where beta_{ij} = beta (1 - sigma_{ij}) * exp(- alpha|i-j|) 

i = 1,2,3,...,N
```

I have written the code below in an attempt to solve the system of differential equations in a spatial network.

```
from jitcode import jitcode, y
import numpy as np
import sympy

#import symengine
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#from scipy.integrate import ode
from numpy.random import uniform

n = 10
alpha = 0.05
#beta = 0.1

beta = uniform(0.01,3.0,n)
beta.sort()
mu = uniform(0.01,3.0,n)
mu.sort()
epsilon = uniform(0.01,3.0,n)
epsilon.sort()
pi = uniform(0.01,3.0,n)
pi.sort()
gamma = uniform(0.01,3.0,n)
gamma.sort()
omega = uniform(0.01,3.0,n)
omega.sort()
zeta = uniform(0.01,3.0,n)
zeta.sort()
rho = uniform(0.01,3.0,n)
rho.sort()
k = uniform(0.01,3.0,n)
k.sort()
c = uniform(0.01,3.0,n)
c.sort()


# Knonecker delta

M = np.einsum('ij-> ij',np.eye(n,n))

print(M)

# Adjacency matrix

A = beta * M * sympy.exp(-alpha) 

print(A)


def f():
    for i in range(n):

    coupling_sum = sum(y(i+2) * y(i) for j in range(n) if A[i, j]
    )
    yield omega[i] - epsilon[i] * y(i+2) * y(i) - mu[i] * y(i)
    yield epsilon[i] * y(i+2) * y(i) - zeta[i] * y(i+1) - rho[i] * y(i+1)* y(i+3)
    yield c[i] * y(i+1) - gamma[i] * y(i+2) + coupling_sum
    yield k[i]* y(i+1) * y(i+3) - delta[i] *y(i+3)

#integrate
#---------------

initial_state = np.random.random(n)

ODE = jitcode(f,n=n)
ODE.set_integrator("dopri5", atol=1e-6,rtol=0)
initial = np.linspace(0.1,0.4,num=n)

ODE.set_initial_value(initial_state,time=0.0)
#data structure: x[0], w[0], v[0], z[0], ..., x[n], w[n], v[n], z[n]
data = []
data = np.vstack(ODE.integrate(T) for T in range(0, 100, 0.1))
print(data)
fig = plt.figure()
```

I am expecting to get solutions for the four differential equations and some simulations to represent the equations. The error message that Iam getting says "RuntimeError: Not Implemented"

Comment: does it comes from jitcode?which line is raising the error? also you seem to have indentation error in f

Comment: Did you mean the linked equation to be `dv_i/dt = c_i * y_i - gamma_i * v_i - \sum_{j neq i} beta_{ij} * v_j * x_j`? The implementation of this equation can not really be connected to what the equation says, neither can be used to make sense of the other.

Comment: The error message is coming from the line before print(data) code. i.e. data = np.vstack.... The message now says TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. The coupling_sum is the invading viral particles for a population of n individuals that are connected in a network, thus it is added to the viral population on dv_i / dt

Comment: I used the adjacency matrix A[i j] to model beta_{ij}. How can i do this better?

Comment: Please comment further on what your system represents. I read from your formulas that in each cell the basis population is `x`, which is constantly created and has a die-off rate. Whenever an `x` and and `y` meet, there is some chance that the `x` gets converted into an `y`. The same with `y` and `z`. On top of that there is the `v` population that has a creation by spontaneous conversion from `y`, dies at some rate and is created when a local `v` meets a cell-foreign `x`.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to a different one after it has been answered. I rolled back your last edit to keep things consistent. If you have a new question on plotting, ask it separately, preferably using some simple array as an example and not something created by a complicated ODE.

Answer (score 1):

Your translation of the model into code has index problems. You addressed this once in the sum calculation, but then never again. To help with that, define helper functions

```py
def X(i): return y(4*i)
def Y(i): return y(4*i+1)
def V(i): return y(4*i+2)
def Z(i): return y(4*i+3)
```

Then you can express the generator of the symbolic right sides as

```py
def f():
    for i in range(n):

        coupling_sum = V(i) * sum(beta[i,j]*X(j) for j in range(n) if j!=i )
        yield omega[i] - epsilon[i] * Y(i) * X(i) - mu[i] * X(i)
        yield epsilon[i] * Y(i) * X(i) - zeta[i] * Y(i) - rho[i] * Y(i)*Z(i)
        yield c[i] * Y(i) - gamma[i] * V(i) + coupling_sum
        yield k[i] * Y(i) * Z(i) - delta[i] * Z(i)
```

with an appropriate definition of `beta[i,j]`. The code you wrote is strange and does not match the formula. In the formula, `beta` is first a constant and then a matrix. In the code, `beta` is an array. This is quite incompatible.

In the call to compile the function, you also should give the correct dimension of the state space, you have `n` components of `x,y,v,z`, making `4*n` components in total.

```py
initial_state = np.random.random(4*n)
ODE = jitcode(f,n=4*n)
```

With the correct dimension of the state space arguments, the integration calls probably will go through.